# GWT Logging only shows Level SERVE

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, logging

I use [GWT Logging](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html) with a simple web application project. I have the following on my module gwt.xml:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler"
    value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED" />
```

In my onModuleLoad function I set:

```
Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
rootLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "root SEVERE");
rootLogger.log(Level.INFO, "root INFO");
```

When I run the app in SuperDevMode I get the following output in my browser console:

```
root SEVERE
```

Even with log level INFO I do not get the info log message.

**How do I get all GWT log level to be displayed?**

Answer (score 0):

Check your GWT run configuration.  On the Arguments tab, you should see something like this:

-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher -war C:\Users\username\workspace\ProjectName\war com.domain.name.ProjectName

If you see "-logLevel SEVERE" instead of "-logLevel INFO", that's your problem.

Comment: You are likely being downvoted because the question is about log level while running the app, while you answered about how to change the log level when *compiling* the app.

Comment: @ColinAlworth Do you have an idea?

Comment: Do you use the switch in the URL? Like "...xyz.html?logLevel=INFO"?

Comment: @ColinAlworth it looks like server run config not compilation run config. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - I posted the GWT Super Dev Mode config, not the Server nor Compiler run config. By default dev mode also starts _a_ web server for your content however, and this `-logLevel` should work for almost any GWT main (precompile, compile, test, dev mode, etc). If compiling/running from maven/groovy/ant of course you may have different ways of passing this argument, and would need more details to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since GWT 2.7.0 you need to explicitly include few properties in your `.gwt.xml` file. This should fix your problem:

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
```

[Source](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ERRAI-822)